# Какие здесь знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

> Ни одного следа ни санного. Ни человеческого, ни звериного не было видно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ни одного следа: ни санного,ни человеческого,ни звериного  - не было видно*.
*Ни одного следа* - выполняет роль обобщающего слова, перед рядом однородных членов ставим двоеточие, после - тире, между однородными - запятые.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно вот так: *"Ни одного следа: ни санного, ни человеческого, ни звериного - не было видно".*